# Boas práticas para Asp.Net MVC 4 - 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Preciso saber como organizar meu projeto na questão das `CRUD's` em caso de haver mais de um Model na minha aplicação.

Por exemplo, possuo o Model aluno e o Model professor.

Crio uma classe do tipo `DbContext` para gerenciar meu banco de dados, mas porém, cada model exigirá suas próprias CRUD's.

Onde será inserido o código das CRUD's? No `DbContext`? Em um `controller master`(um `controller` para `controller's`) ou no próprio `controller` de cada model?

Na resposta peço que passem um exemplo de código em relação a dois models diferentes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Se eu entendi sua dúvida, você precisará ter dois diretórios no seu projeto:

- Controllers (conterá o código de negócio para os CRUDs);

  - Arquivos .cs, **sendo um para cada Model**
- Views (Fará a exibição das informações de cada CRUD);

  - Subdiretórios (um para cada Model)

    - _CreateOrEdit.cshtml
    - Create.cshtml
    - Edit.cshtml
    - Index.cshtml
    - Details.cshtml
    - Delete.cshtml

Um exemplo básico de CRUD é de um cadastro de países (Model `Country`). Lembre-se que por normas o nome do Controller é no plural, e dos subdiretórios das Views também.

**Models\Country.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;

namespace MeuProjeto.Models
{
    [DisplayColumn("Name")]
    public class Country
    {
        [Key]
        public Guid CountryId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display(Name = "Name", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public String Name { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [StringLength(3)]
        [Display(Name = "Acronym", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public String Acronym { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "States", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public virtual ICollection<State> States { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "LastModified", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public DateTime LastModified { get; set; }
        [Display(Name = "CreatedOn", ResourceType = typeof(Resources.Language))]
        public DateTime CreatedOn { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**Controllers\CountriesController.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MeuProjeto.Models;
using MeuProjeto.Resources;

namespace MeuProjeto.Controllers
{   
    public class CountriesController : MeuProjetoController
    {
        private MeuProjetoContext context = new MeuProjetoContext();

        //
        // GET: /Countries/

        [Authorize(Roles = "Administradores")]
        public ViewResult Index()
        {
            return View(context.Countries.Include(country => country.States).ToList());
        }

        //
        // GET: /Countries/Details/5

        [Authorize(Roles = "Administradores")]
        public ViewResult Details(System.Guid id)
        {
            Country country = context.Countries.Single(x => x.CountryId == id);
            return View(country);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Countries/Create

        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        } 

        //
        // POST: /Countries/Create

        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Administradores")]
        public ActionResult Create(Country country)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                country.CountryId = Guid.NewGuid();
                context.Countries.Add(country);
                context.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");  
            }

            return View(country);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Countries/Edit/5

        [Authorize(Roles = "Administradores")]
        public ActionResult Edit(System.Guid id)
        {
            Country country = context.Countries.Single(x => x.CountryId == id);
            return View(country);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Countries/Edit/5

        [HttpPost]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Administradores")]
        public ActionResult Edit(Country country)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                context.Entry(country).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Modified;
                context.SaveChanges();

                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(country);
        }

        //
        // GET: /Countries/Delete/5

        [Authorize(Roles = "Administradores")]
        public ActionResult Delete(System.Guid id)
        {
            Country country = context.Countries.Single(x => x.CountryId == id);
            return View(country);
        }

        //
        // POST: /Countries/Delete/5

        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [Authorize(Roles = "Administradores")]
        public ActionResult DeleteConfirmed(System.Guid id)
        {
            Country country = context.Countries.Single(x => x.CountryId == id);
            context.Countries.Remove(country);
            context.SaveChanges();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing) {
                context.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

Acho que não precisa dos códigos de cada View, mas se precisar, é só falar.

Não sei se preciso passar mais um código de Controller porque eles são parecidos entre si, mas se for mesmo preciso, novamente, é só falar.

Comment: Boa a resposta, mas ainda não tirou minha dúvida. A idéia era no caso de ter mais de um model que também necessite de CRUD's, seria montado da mesma forma porém no controller deste model as CRUD's dele?

Comment: Isso. Cada `model` pede um `controller` em separado, por questões de organização.

Comment: A minha dúvida era quanto a quantidade de CRUD's, mas pelo visto então é o correto... Valeu!